# Parser Combinators - Simple grammar

Tags: parsing, scala, context-free-grammar, parser-combinators

I am trying to use parser combinators in Scala on a simple grammar that I have copied from a book. When I run the following code it stops immediately after the first token has been parsed with the error

`[1.3] failure: string matching regex '\z' expected but '+' found`

I can see why things go wrong. The first token is an expression and therefor it is the only thing that needs to be parsed according to the grammar. However I do not know what is a good way to fix it.

```
object SimpleParser extends RegexParsers 
{
    def Name = """[a-zA-Z]+""".r
    def Int = """[0-9]+""".r

    def Main:Parser[Any] = Expr
    def Expr:Parser[Any] = 
    (
          Term
        | Term <~ "+" ~> Expr
        | Term <~ "-" ~> Expr
    )

    def Term:Parser[Any] = 
    (
          Factor
        | Factor <~ "*" ~> Term
    )

    def Factor:Parser[Any] =
    (
          Name
        | Int 
        | "-" ~> Int 
        | "(" ~> Expr <~ ")" 
        | "let" ~> Name <~ "=" ~> Expr <~ "in" ~> Expr <~ "end" 
    )

    def main(args: Array[String]) 
    {
        var input = "2 + 2"
        println(input)
        println(parseAll(Main, input))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Factor <~ "*" ~> Term` means `Factor.<~("*" ~> Term)`, so the whole right part is dropped.
Use `Factor ~ "*" ~ Term ^^ { case f ~ _ ~ t => ??? }` or `rep1sep`:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

object SimpleParser extends RegexParsers
{
    def Name = """[a-zA-Z]+""".r
    def Int = """[0-9]+""".r

    def Main:Parser[Any] = Expr
    def Expr:Parser[Any] = rep1sep(Term, "+" | "-")

    def Term:Parser[Any] = rep1sep(Factor, "*")

    def Factor:Parser[Any] =
    (
          "let" ~> Name ~ "=" ~ Expr ~ "in" ~ Expr <~ "end" ^^ { case n ~ _ ~ e1 ~ _ ~ e2 => (n, e1, e2)
        | Int
        | "-" ~> Int
        | "(" ~> Expr <~ ")"
        | Name }
    )
}

SimpleParser.parseAll(SimpleParser.Main, "2 + 2")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
defined module SimpleParser
res1: SimpleParser.ParseResult[Any] = [1.6] parsed: List(List(2), List(2))
```

The second part of parser `def Term:Parser[Any] = Factor | Factor <~ "*" ~> Term` is useless. The first part, `Factor`, can parse (with non-empty `next`) any `Input` that the second part, `Factor <~ "*" ~> Term`, is able to parse.

Comment: Thanks! I can understand that I use <~ and ~> in a wrong way. But I can't see why it is necessary to use rep1sep. What was wrong with the way it was before?

Comment: `rep1sep` is just shorter.

Comment: You can replace `def Term:Parser[Any] = rep1sep(Factor, "*")` with `def Term:Parser[Any] = Factor ~ "*" ~ Term ^^ { case f ~ _ ~ t => (f, t) } | Factor`.

Comment: @MadsAndersen, it's necessary to use `Factor ~ "*" ~ Term | Factor` instead of `Factor | Factor ~ "*" ~ Term`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I have learned that the order of rules are important. Fx, it is necessary that the let-definition is before the name-definition.